# RAID1 setting in S5520HCR

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid

How do you set up RAID1 in the BIOS of an Intel S5520HCR server motherboard?

When I try to create a RAID1 array, I cannot install Windows Server 2008. The error it gives me is `Installation path was not found` and no drives are visible when trying to install Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Please don't yell.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to not bother - the S5520HCR's on board RAID offloads all processing to the OS driver and main CPU, if you want to use RAID on this system do it in software.

If you really want to do this then there are instructions on what to do for Windows 2008, Red Hat and SUSE on [this Intel support page](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/sb/CS-030677.htm).